# How do I use Excel to load product backlog items, bugs, etc. into TFS/VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do I use Excel to load product backlog items, bugs, tasks, etc. into Team Foundation Server/VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've installed Visual Studio 2010 (along with the TFS 2010 client), you should have a new tab on the Excel ribbon bar that is labeled "Team".  Using this, you can access any Team Project work item query (either a "My Query" or a "Team Query").

These queries return data that can be read, changed, or added to. Once you've added the appropriate rows, simply go back to the Team tab and click on "Publish".